# Octave : use anonymous function inside function

Tags: function, octave, anonymous

Is there a way in Octave to use anonymous functions inside of a function?
I want to avoid having a dependency between the function file and the config file.
The link to the config file should only be from inside main.m.

---

My project has the following file structure:

```
% config.m
ms2kmh = @(v) v * 3.6;
```

```
% main.m
source('config.m');
source('application.m');
```

```
% application_xy.m
x = 1;
y = 2;
A = function_xy(x, y)
```

```
% function_xy.m
function A = function_xy(x, y)
    source('config.m'); % <-- want to avoid this line
    A = x * ms2kmh(y);
end
```

---

thank you

Comment: Create a file with the function, and add the folder where the file is to your path. If you need the anonymous function in multiple scopes, then apparently it shouldn't be an anonymous function.

Comment: True - but, on the other hands side, it is quite overkill to create a bunch of files, containing only single line functions.

Comment: I guess that `config.m` contains various constants and thus function handles that are needed throughout the project. You can collect all these variables (even function handles) in a struct, and pass this struct as an input argument to all the function that need it.

Comment: Exactly - I will try your way - was thinking it were a more elegant to define as a global variable what is actually a gobal - and also with functions - i will indeed put all the functions in seperate files, which will solve the problem and will still make the code super readable - thank you

Comment: `source` is not a MATLAB function, tag removed

Comment: Nothing stops you from defining multiple functions on your `config.m` file. You just need to make sure that the first statement is not a function block. Typically, that's something like a simple `1;` So do something like `1; function foo() ... endfuunction; function bar() ... endfunction`. But really, it seems to be that if `ms2kmh` is a config, then it's the job of your program to pass it to the functions, so add it as an argument to `function_xy`.

Comment: it seems to me your code is asking to become a class

Comment: You could define `ms2kmh` as `global`. It's not recommended to use global variables, but it seems that this is what what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to create an object with state (in this case, the x, y inputs, and the desired function handle). E.g.

```
% @application_xy/application_xy.m
function Obj = application_xy(x, y, fhandle)
  Obj = struct( 'x', x, 'y', y, 'f', fhandle );
  Obj = class( Obj, 'application_xy' );
end
```

```
% @application_xy/function_xy.m
function A = function_xy(Obj)
    A = Obj.x * Obj.f( Obj.y );
end
```

```
% config.m
ms2kmh = @(v) v * 3.6;
```

```
% main.m
source('config.m');
MyObj = application_xy(1, 2, ms2kmh );
A = function_xy( MyObj )
```

[This is the manual entry on object oriented programming in octave](http://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Object-Oriented-Programming.html) if you're not too familiar with it and would like to read more.